# Is it possible to upload binary not only agent but member too?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

Working in team for an iOS project. Because owner has no experience with iOS, he shared the `agent` account username / password with me, to be able to submit binary to iTunesConnect, because as `admin` I was not able to send binary.

Any way to submit binary without his credentials?

Sending app for beta testing is my goal right now to do as `admin`.

Comment: my answer is clear and helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

@Janos All the users with `Admin`, `Technical` & `Legal` role in iTunes connect can submit binary to iTunes for review. All the users with `Manage Your Apps` capability can `submit binary`.

You can go through roles & access of users in [Apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UsingiTunesConnect/UsingiTunesConnect.html)

I hope it helps you.